# How to concatenate values in to a comma seperated values in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am reading text file where I would like to get values based on condition. First I will take FREQ  where CELLID = 639 and ISMAINBCCH=YES,that I have done now next task is I have to concatenate FREQ values in a comma separated way where CELLID=639 and ISMAINBCCH=NO, so the output I want is 24,28,67. How to achieve that?

lines are

```
ADD GCELL:CELLID=639, CELLNAME="NR_0702_07021_G1_A", MCC="424", MNC="02", LAC=6112, CI=7021, NCC=6, BCC=0, EXTTP=Normal_cell, IUOTP=Concentric_cell, ENIUO=ON, DBFREQBCCHIUO=Extra, FLEXMAIO=OFF, CSVSP=3, CSDSP=5, PSHPSP=4, PSLPSVP=6, BSPBCCHBLKS=1, BSPAGBLKSRES=4, BSPRACHBLKS=1, TYPE=GSM900_DCS1800, 
......................
.............

ADD GTRX:TRXID=0, TRXNAME="M_RAK_JeerExch_G_1879_18791_A-0", FREQ=81, TRXNO=0, CELLID=639, IDTYPE=BYID, ISMAINBCCH=YES, ISTMPTRX=NO, GTRXGROUPID=2556;
ADD GTRX:TRXID=1, TRXNAME="M_RAK_JeerExch_G_1879_18791_A-1", FREQ=24, TRXNO=1, CELLID=639, IDTYPE=BYID, ISMAINBCCH=NO, ISTMPTRX=NO, GTRXGROUPID=2556;
ADD GTRX:TRXID=5, TRXNAME="M_RAK_JeerExch_G_1879_18791_A-2", FREQ=28, TRXNO=2, CELLID=639, IDTYPE=BYID, ISMAINBCCH=NO, ISTMPTRX=NO, GTRXGROUPID=2556;
ADD GTRX:TRXID=6, TRXNAME="M_RAK_JeerExch_G_1879_18791_A-3", FREQ=67, TRXNO=3, CELLID=639, IDTYPE=BYID, ISMAINBCCH=NO, ISTMPTRX=NO, GTRXGROUPID=2556;
```

**Update**

I am getting values like shown below

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filename))
{
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (s.Contains("ADD GCELL:"))
        {
            var gtrx = new Gtrx
            {
                CellId = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "CELLID")),
                Freq = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "FREQ")),
                TrxNo = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "TRXNO")),
                IsMainBcch = PullValue(s, "ISMAINBCCH").ToUpper() == "YES",
                TrxName = PullValue(s, "TRXNAME"),

            };

        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I used facade concept, but now it is taking lot of time. I am not sure whether I am using any bad logic two times I am iterating text file one for getting regular values and other for getting concatenated values

```
 private class Gtrx
    {
        public int Freq { get; set; }
        public int TrxNo { get; set; }
        public string TrxName { get; set; }
        public int CellId { get; set; }
        public bool IsMainBcch { get; set; }
    }

    private class Gcell
    {
        public int CellId { get; set; }
        public string CellName { get; set; }
        public string Mcc { get; set; }
        public int Lac { get; set; }
        public int Ci { get; set; }
    }
    private class GcellGtrx
    {
        public Gcell Gcell { get; set; }
        public Gtrx Gtrx { get; set; }
    }

using (var sr = new StringReader(data))
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        line = line.Trim();
        if (line.StartsWith("ADD GCELL:"))
        {
            var gcell = new Gcell
            {
                CellId = int.Parse(PullValue(line, "CELLID")),
                CellName = PullValue(line, "CELLNAME"),
                Ci = int.Parse(PullValue(line, "CI")),
                Lac = int.Parse(PullValue(line, "LAC")),
                Mcc = PullValue(line, "MCC")
            };
            var gcellGtrx = new GcellGtrx();
            gcellGtrx.Gcell = gcell;
            _dictionary.Add(gcell.CellId, gcellGtrx);
        }
        if (line.StartsWith("ADD GTRX:"))
        {
            var gtrx = new Gtrx
            {
                CellId = int.Parse(PullValue(line, "CELLID")),
                Freq = int.Parse(PullValue(line, "FREQ")),
                TrxNo = int.Parse(PullValue(line, "TRXNO")),
                IsMainBcch = PullValue(line, "ISMAINBCCH").ToUpper() == "YES",
DEFINED_TCH_FRQ = null,
                TrxName = PullValue(line, "TRXNAME")
            };

           if (!intarr.Contains(gtrx.CellId))
                            {

                                if (!_dictionary.ContainsKey(gtrx.CellId))
                                {
                                    // No GCell record for this id. Do something!
                                    continue;
                                }
                                intarr.Add(gtrx.CellId);
                                string results = string.Empty;

                                    var result = String.Join(",",
        from ss in File.ReadLines(filename)
        where ss.Contains("ADD GTRX:")
        where int.Parse(PullValue(ss, "CELLID")) == gtrx.CellId
        where PullValue(ss, "ISMAINBCCH").ToUpper() != "YES"
        select int.Parse(PullValue(ss, "FREQ")));
                                    results = result;


                                var gtrxnew = new Gtrx
                                {
                                    DEFINED_TCH_FRQ = results
                                };

                                _dictionary[gtrx.CellId].Gtrx = gtrx;
        }
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Finally I did it like first I saved lines starting with ADD GTRX in to an array by using File. Readalllines and then used only that array to get concatenated string instead of storing entire text file and got some performance improvement.

If I convert my Text files that contain hundreds of thousands of lines each into xml and then retrieve data from xml file rather from text file, will it make any performance improvement? If I use datatable and dataset rather than classes here will be a performance improvement?

Comment: Please show the code you've already got - if you already have the right values, it may be as simple as `string.Join(",", values)` but it's unclear what you've actually got so far...

Comment: @Jon Skeet i updated my question

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code - I'm sure it doesn't look like that in your real source code. Don't make it hard for others to read. And while you've shown *some* code, it's still not clear what you want out of this. (Heck, you don't even use `gtrx`...) A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would make it easier to help you...

Comment: @Jon Skeet i updated my question, i did it by using facade concept, but it is taking lot of time ,i am processing textfile two time one for getting regular values and other for concatenated values by using File.Readlines, is there any bad logic or a different way

Comment: Why are you not using a JSON library? This is *way* too much (very badly formatted) code - and still not a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet i don't know the usage of Jason here , i used it in Asp.net mvc for passing values from controller to view.Here i am taking values from two lines which is occurring multiple times in a text file ,one is begging with Add gcell and other is Add Gtrx ,

Comment: Apologies, I was confusing this question with another one. It's still not a short but complete program demonstrating the problem though - and the parsing is still all over the place. (I don't expect your code looks like that in Visual Studio.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet now i got a simple logic ,but i dont know how to implement.What i noted is in order to make concatenated string, the only thing i have to do is take 10 lines above and below rather using File.Readalllines, but i dont know how to implement it.Could you please suggest

Comment: No, I *still* don't understand your question. What do you mean by "the only thing i have to do is take 10 lines above and 10 lines below"? Above and below what? Please read the page I linked to earlier, and put a *lot* more effort into clarifying your question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Finally i did it like first i saved lines starting with ADD GTRX in to an array by using File.Readalllines and then used only that array to get concatenated string instead of storing entire text file and got some performance improvement.Now my question is if i convert my Text files each contain lakhs of lines in to xml and then retrieve data from xml file, will it make any perfomance improvement? if i use datatable and dataset rather than classes here will it make any perfomance improvement?

Comment: Well have you tried it? But no, I wouldn't expect it to improve the *performance* - but it may well make the file easier to use for everyone else. (Please bear in mind that "lakhs" isn't a word in common use in English outside certain cultures. On Stack Overflow, it's better to explicitly say "hundreds of thousands of lines".)

Comment: @Jon Skeet ,thanks :), so  you mean converting textfile in to xml will not make any perfomance improvement?i dont know whether i can give some structure for that xml or by using xslt, but if i can give ,will it make any improvement rather than accessing textfile line by line .What about using datatable instead of class files and store in to datasets

Comment: We're now a long way from the original question. Please ask a new question if you want to continue this.

Answer (score 0):

Create `gtrxs` collection to store `Gtrx` objects and read data from file in to `gtrxs`. Then you can use LINQ (ming need to add `using System.Linq;`) to find `Gtrx` objects that are matching your requirements and call `Select` to get list of `Freq` values. Once you have a list, you can simply use `String.Join(",", freqValues)` to build up CSV string.

```
var gtrxs = new List<Gtrx>();

using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filename))
{
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {


        if (s.Contains("ADD GCELL:"))
        {

            var gtrx = new Gtrx
                                {
                                    CellId = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "CELLID")),
                                    Freq = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "FREQ")),
                                    TrxNo = int.Parse(PullValue(s, "TRXNO")),
                                    IsMainBcch = PullValue(s, "ISMAINBCCH").ToUpper() == "YES",
                                    TrxName = PullValue(s, "TRXNAME"),

                                };

            gtrxs.Add(gtrx);
        }
    }
}

IEnumerable<int> freqValues = gtrxs.Where(x => x.CellId == 639 && x.IsMainBcch == false).Select(x => x.Freq);
string result = String.Join(",", freqValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
var result = String.Join(",", 
    from s in File.ReadAllLines(filename)
    where s.Contains("ADD GCELL:")
    where int.Parse(PullValue(s, "CELLID")) == 639
    where PullValue(s, "ISMAINBCCH").ToUpper() != "YES"
    select int.Parse(PullValue(s, "FREQ")));
```